SqlException taking backup by using asp.net console application
When i am taking backup from live server by using Sql Management in asp.net core console application.
Error:

SqlException: Cannot open backup device 'C:\DB-Backup\finnid_live2_backup_20240618_113003.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

directory is created
want to tacking backup.

C:\DB-Backup must exist on the SQL Server machine, not in the machine that runs the ASP.NET app. Additionally, the SQL Server service account must have permissions to write to C:\DB-Backup

must have permissions to write to we can right click on the C:\DB-Backup -> select "Properties" -> "Security" tab -> edit permission to make sure that the windows account has read & write permission to this folder.
